# ESXi VM to Physical server on the same hardware

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

I have a Physical server running ESXi 6.0 with a single 64Tb Datastore, One of my VMs has grown to almost 50Tb on this host.

I think at this point the best approach is to convert the VM to take over the entire bare-metal host and replace the ESXi Hypervisor with CentOS which is installed on the VM.

Is there a way to achieve this without a third party server with similar specs for the transition?

Or should I just keep the ESXi and run the single VM on it expanded to 100% of all host resources?

Comment: Virtualisation adds a little overhead and some license cost compared to running a bare metal server but has the advantage that it abstracts the hardware. Your use case might benefit from the bare metal performance or from an operations perspective it might be useful to only run VM's  and even one-on-one virtualization might then be "preferable" to the alternative as that allows you a single deployment/backup/fail-over/management/upgrade strategy.

Answer (score 0):

A V2P migration may not be necessary. Giant VMs are fine, you can use all of a host's CPU memory and storage on one VM if you like.

For the cost of a license fee and a small amount of overhead, you gain operational flexibility. Manage all your VMs in one place with the same procedures. Add another host for HA. Do clever things with virtual switches.

To migrate, the host needs to take downtime, to replace its bare metal OS of ESXi with CentOS. Also required is a migration plan for the storage. Whether you need to make arrangements to run the workload on a different host depends on how much downtime your organization allows.